# defining 'clickable' using dropzone with angular.js controllers/templates when the button is in another controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, dropzone

I'm getting an *"Error: Invalid `clickable` option provided."* now that I have split an existing two into two separate parts handled by angular controllers

I need to know how to set the 'clickable' option in one controller with a button/element that is in a template of another controller.

**CONTEXT**

I'm moving an upload tool into angular and originally the entire thing was done with a single static template. There was an html element 'above' the dropzone container that is used for the
'clickable' value to pop up a file dialog for dropzone if the user doesn't want to drag-and-drop onto the dropzone area/container itself.

Since that button is now part of another controller with it's own template, I cannot immediately reference it by the standard methods (class name was what the old code was using, but element id doesn't work either)

Presumably, the 'ControlsController' that handles the buttons along the top isn't loaded or is otherwise unavailable when the DropzoneController is trying to create the Dropzone instance.  So I need to find another way to set the button as clickable.

I have a global angular 'service' class available now or could use something like $rootScope or $broadcast/$emit but I'm not entirely sure how to do that and to ensure that both items are available when needed.
I assume I can likely set the dropzone 'clickable' option after it's instantiated, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that from two separate controllers each handling two different parts of the user interface, especially when I can't be entirely sure in either controller when/if the other one is instantiated or if it is available yet.

I tried using an $onInit() to create the new Dropzone() (in the DropzoneController) but it still says *"Error: Invalid `clickable` option provided"*

Is there some way I can either pull the element definition out of the Controls template inside the component/controller?  Or is there a better way to trigger a behavior between one controller and the other?

**CODE SNIPPETS**

the ControlsController is tied to a component/element at the top of the UI.

The DropzoneController is attached to a *div* surrounding a list of user image files displayed with other angular controllers inside that div:

```
<div id="ImageSelector" class="ImageSelectorS3Window S3FullWindowHeight">

    <selector-controls></selector-controls>

    <div class="ImageSelector List Unselectable dropzone" id="ImageSelectorList" ng-controller="DropzoneController">
            <user-folder ng-repeat="(folder, pseudodir) in subdirs" folder="folder" pseudodir="pseudodir"></user-folder>
            <uploaded-image  ng-repeat="(filename, image) in uploadedImages" filename="filename" image="image"></uploaded-image>
    </div>
</div>
```

the Controls template looks like the following and gets loaded in place of *selector-controls* in the above template:

```
<div class="ImageSelector" id="ImageSelectorControl">
    <div class="UIBar">
        <img id="ISUpFolder" class="UIButton Transparent" src="images/arrow86.png" title="Go Up a Folder">
        <img id="ISRefresh" class="UIButton" src="images/refresh7.png" title="Refresh">
        <img id="ISCreateFolder" class="UIButton" src="images/new6.png" title="Create Folder">
        <img class="UIButton ImageSelectorUploadButton dz-clickable" src="images/mini.png" title="Upload File(s)">
        <img id="ISMove" class="UIButton Transparent" src="images/custom-move.png" title="Move Selected">
        <img id="ISRename" class="UIButton Transparent" src="images/interface19.png" title="Rename Selected">
        <img id="ISDelete" class="UIButton Transparent" src="images/mini2.png" title="Delete Selected">
        <img id="ISHelp" class="UIButton" src="images/question3.png" title="Help">
    </div>
    <div id="ImageSelectorFolder" class="ImageSelectorFolder" title="Main">Folder: Main</div>
</div>
```

The current value in the Dropzone options for clickable is '.ImageSelectorUploadButton'

Answer (score 1):

rather than importing in $rootScope, I have access to it in a service already (so I can import $rootScope to directly modify global settings or use the service to programmatically modify those settings)

Since the controlsController already has the settingsService injected, I created a broadcastClickableLoaded() method in the service:

**settingService.js method:**

```
broadcastClickableLoaded: function(clickable)
{
    this.$rootScope.$broadcast("clickableLoaded", clickable)
}
```

then I additionally injected $element into the ControlsController class, created an $onInit method to find the clickable element, and trigger the service method:

**ControlsController class $onInit method**

```
ControlsController.prototype.$onInit = function() {
    let clickable = this.$element.find(".ImageSelectorUploadButton")[0]
    this.settingsService.broadcastClickableLoaded(clickable)
}
```

Then in my dropzone controller, I can set an event handler to catch the broadcast event to create the Dropzone() only when the controller broadcasts (via the service) it is loaded and available:

**DropzoneController $on event handler**

```
this.$scope.$on("clickableLoaded", (evt, clickable) => {
    // includes
    //          dropzone area element as first parameter
    //          clickable element as second parameter
    this.createDropzone(this.$element[0], clickable)
})
```